# Replacing word in CSV without knowing it's position with python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to find occurrences of the word NIL inside several huge CSV files and replace them for an empty string. I've looked up solutions but the one **I tried doesn't work because the line is a list** and the other ones I've found seem to be with specific position but I can't know where the NIL will appear because the files are always changing.

My code:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog, os, csv

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
    for file in files:
        with open (os.path.join(subdir, file), 'rb') as csvfile:
            #Check if the file has headers#
            if 'Result  :  Query Result' in csvfile.readline():
                with open(os.path.join(subdir, os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '_no_headers_no_nil.csv'), 'wb') as out:
                    reader = csv.reader(csvfile.readlines()[6:], delimiter=',')
                    writer = csv.writer(out)
                    for row in reader:
                        #replace NIL occurrences with empty strings
                        row = row.replace('NIL', '')
                        separated = row.split(',')
                        writer.writerow(row)

            else:
                #The file doesn't have headers
                #find and replace NIL occurrences goes here
                print 'file skipped ' + file + ': No headers found'
```

and here's an example of the type of CSVs

[image: csv example]

Comment: what happens if the text contains something like `VANILLA`?

Comment: @MarcB It won't, it's only numbers but if it doesn't get a value then it returns NIL

Comment: @MarcB, row should be a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  a try/except if *Nil* is not in every row getting the index and just assign to an empty string:

```
try:

    row[row.index("NIL")] = ""
except IndexError:
    pass
```

*index* will find where Nil is in your list, once you have that the assignment will replace it:

```
In [9]: lst = ["NIL", "foo"]

In [10]: lst[lst.index("NIL")] = ""

In [11]: lst
Out[11]: ['', 'foo']
```

Since you can have multiple `NIL` strings per row, you will need to loop over each element:

```
row[:] = [ele if ele != "NIL" else "" for ele in row]
```

Also you don't need to call readlines, you can use *itertools.islice* to start at the nth line:

```
from itertools import islice

reader = csv.reader(islice(csvfile, 6, None), delimiter=',')
```

Comment: This was so helpful! Thank you very much.